# Conceptual definition of the extension of a connection to 1-forms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, connections

I have a question that arose while reading Milnor's "Characteristic Classes".  I will use the notation from that book.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $\zeta$ be a complex vector bundle on $M$.  Milnor defines a connection on $M$ to be a map $\nabla\colon C^{\infty}(\zeta) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(\tau_{\mathbb{C}}^{\ast} \otimes \zeta)$ satisfying the Leibniz identity, where $\tau_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the complexified tangent bundle of $M$.

In Lemma 4 of Appendix C, he proves that such a connection can be extended to a map $\hat{\nabla}\colon C^{\infty}(\tau_{\mathbb{C}}^{\ast} \otimes \zeta) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(\wedge^2 \tau_{\mathbb{C}}^{\ast} \otimes \zeta)$ satisfying an appropriate Leibniz rule.  However, his proof is just a definition in local coordinates, with the details left to the reader.  I verified these details, though they were a bit of a pain.

However, I feel like there must be a more conceptual definition of $\hat{\nabla}$ that makes no reference to local coordinates.  Does anyone know one?

Comment: I do not have the book at hand, but are you sure that the notation is $\Delta$ and not $\nabla$? (The latter is obtained with `\nabla`.) Anyway, since it is not of research level, this question is more appropriate for [Math.SE].

Comment: @AlexM.: You're right, I fixed the notation.  As far as the level of this question, it arose while reading an advanced monograph (in fact, one I am teaching a grad topics course from right now), and I am a tenured full professor working in geometry/topology but do not know the answer.  So it seems a little rude to point me instead to a website devoted to helping undergrads cheat.

Comment: MSE is certainly *not* a website *devoted* to helping undergrads cheat.

Comment: I would like to join @Z.M in saying that highlighting the bad behaviour of a few MSE users devalues the people who put genuine effort into both questions and answers there.  I would encourage the original poster to delete your second comment, and possibly also to replace the first by a comment that describes your qualifications without denigrating anyone else.

Comment: @Linda I apologize - many here do not like to pass out intuition freely to those with low ratings. I'm not exactly sure about your geometric setting, but in some algebraic settings your map can be thought of as the dual of a Lie bracket and induces a map from derivations to endomorphisms which is a Lie homomorphism exactly when the connection is integrable. See Katz-Oda - On the differentiation... p201

Comment: @LSpice: I was the one who was insulted, but somehow I'm out of line?  And now a moderator has deleted my second comment?  I suppose this is all consistent with this website's reputation, but I am still disappointed.

Comment: I have opened a meta discussion about this question at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5182

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems like a fine question. I am in the habit of asking what some might call "beginner-ish" questions in areas I am not hugely familiar with; however, I have been here for ages and people see the rep and give me the opportunity to ask such questions. Someone who is a completely fresh user should be treated with at least the benefit of the doubt, and when more context turns up, but it is not a perfect process. My only humble suggestion would have been to explicitly give some context in the question up front (eg "I am teaching a grad topics course, and ....")

Comment: @Linda I would like to apologise on behalf of the larger community, and ask you to please stick around. Someone putting this kind of thought into mathematics is exactly the sort of person that has good contributions to make here.

Comment: @Linda: I've been on this site for some time and I'm afraid that comments like that of Alex. M. abound on this site. It's interesting to me that you've said that this is inline with reputation of this site. I had a similar kind of question that arose whilst I was looking over an advanced monograph on differential geometry and I was looking for clues as to how to understand its description of a Noether theorem. It was down-voted and closed here, so no help there with quite a bit of sniping that it didn't deserve to be there. As it is,  I solved it to my satisfaction on my own ...

Comment: @Linda: ... I'm glad that you called them out on this. They deserve to be.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If we denote by $\nabla$ the connection on $E\to M$, then we can define an exterior differential $d^\nabla:\Gamma(\Lambda^pM\otimes E)\to\Gamma(\Lambda^{p+1} M\otimes E) $ by
$$ d^\nabla \alpha (X_0,\dots, X_p) = 
\sum_i (-1)^i \nabla_{X_i}(\alpha(\tilde{X_0}, \dots , \hat {\tilde{X_i}}, \dots, \tilde X_p))
 + \sum_{i\neq j} -(1)^{i+j} \alpha ([\tilde X_i, \tilde X_j], X_0, \dots, \hat X_i,\dots, \hat X_j, \dots, X_p).$$

where $X_i\in T_x M$;  $\tilde X_i$ denotes an extension of $X_i$ to a neighbourhood of $x\in M$, and the  hat above something denotes that that argument has been omitted.

This formula can be found in Besse's book "Einstein Manifolds" pg 24, beware I recall there are a few typos in that part of the book.

The pattern for this definition is the usual one used to extend the covariant derivative to the tensor algebra, modified by alternating the result and using the covariant derivative.

Comment: Oh, that's really helpful, thanks!  So you really can define it just like the usual $d$ operator.  I'll check out Besse's book.  Strangely enough, I have it on my shelf but have never opened it -- I inherited it from a retiring colleague several years ago.

Comment: @Linda I recommend that book very highly: it has both a wealth of information (about much more than just Einstein manfolds) and is organized in a very clear way. The first chapter also has some nice less-formal discussion.

Comment: @Linda: The same formula is in Michor's *Natural Operations in Differential Geometry*.

Answer (score 3):

Although the answer is already given, it may be helpful to point out how the coordinate definition contains the multilinear definition, in a single step of work. From the definition
$$(d^\nabla s)_{ij}^\alpha=\frac{\partial s_j^\alpha}{\partial x^i}-\frac{\partial s_i^\alpha}{\partial x^j}+\Gamma_{i\beta}^\alpha s_j^\beta-\Gamma_{j\beta}^\alpha s_i^\beta$$
you can contract with $X^iY^j$ to get (using product rule from calculus twice)
$$(d^\nabla s)(X,Y)^\alpha=\Big(\frac{\partial (s(Y))^\alpha}{\partial x^i}-s_j^\alpha\frac{\partial Y^j}{\partial x^i}\Big)X^i-\Big(\frac{\partial (s(X))^\alpha}{\partial x^j}-s_i^\alpha\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\Big)Y^j+\Gamma_{i\beta}^\alpha s(Y)^\beta X^i-\Gamma_{j\beta}^\alpha s(X)^\beta Y^j.$$
The first and fifth terms form the definition of $\nabla_X(s(Y))$, the third and sixth terms form the definition of $\nabla_Y(s(X))$, and the second and fourth terms define $-s([X,Y]).$ So you have
$$(d^\nabla s)(X,Y)=\nabla_X(s(Y))-\nabla_Y(s(X))-s([X,Y]).$$